# API standard design - swagger parameter body VS URI

Tags: api, swagger, restful-url

I would like to clarify what is the design standard to query a list of array.

**json data:**

```
  "ids": [
    {
      "id": "bbbbeeee1111",
      "type": "student"
    },
        {
      "id": "bbbbeeee2222",
      "type": "teacher"
    }
  ],
```

GET endpoint

```
/api/testitem
```

swagger parameter body

```
{ 
 "ids": ["bbbbeeee1111;student"]
}
```

swagger returned the URI like this , the %3B seems wrong. some coding issues at API design?

```
http://localhost:8888/api/testitem?ids=bbbbeeee1111%3Bstudent
```

Comment: The URLs in the "seems wrong" and "this works" examples are the same. What URL actually works and what does not work? Can you also post your OpenAPI/Swagger definition (YAML/JSON file)?

Comment: @Helen /swagger/v2/swagger.json  i removed POSTMAN comment, as it is confusing.

Comment: `%3B` is the percent-encoded `;` character. Why do you think this format is wrong? Does your API expect parameters in another format?

Comment: @Helen yes I knew its kind of encoding from ; to %3B. So that's alright when expose URI in such format? If I have to use any API tools, then I need to manual put the %3B instead of exact string.